# Inserir variável em valor de animate jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando inserir esse valor no scrollTop mas não esta retornando, algum problema?

```
var top = $('.sku').offset().top;

$(window).animate({
    scrollTop: top
}, 500)
```

Comment: Em que momento está inicializando essa variavel `top`? certifique-se de que o elemento já tenha sido renderizado para pegar a posição dele, senão sempre vai retornar 0.

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo Sou meia leiga no assunto, poderia dar um exemplo ou algum documento para eu dar uma olhada?

Comment: Está chamando isso dentro de um `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` ou `$(function(){ .. })`?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, thanks!

Comment: Sempre que possível coloque seu `javascript` no final da tag `<body>`, antes do fechamento dela.

Comment: Já formulo um resposta mais explicativa para futuras pesquisas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certifique-se de pegar a posição do elemento depois de ele ter sido renderizado, veja o exemplo:

```
<head>
    ... estilos e tudo mais

    <script>
        var top = $("div").offset().top; // vai retornar 0, porque o elemento ainda não foi renderizado
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div style="top: 200px;">Teste</div>

    <script>
        var top = $("div").offset().top; // vai retornar o valor correto pois o elemento foi renderizado
    </script>

</body>
```

Como boas práticas recomenda-se colocar o `javascript` (inclusive os imports) no final da pagina antes do fechamento da tag `<body>`, pois o navegador bloqueia a renderização até que esses scripts sejam carregados:

```
<body>

    ... Seu conteudo html

    // Vai carregar  js depois que a pagina for renderizada
    <script type="text/javascript" src="arquivo.js"></script>
    <script>
        ... Seus scripts
    </script>

</body>
```

E ainda você pode usar o [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) do `Jquery` para executar um script apenas quando o documento estiver pronto:

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
              altert("pronto");
         })

         // ou a versão simplificada dele
         $(function() {
              altert("pronto");
         })

    </script>
```

Comment: Boa!! Ótimo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Em principio o valor deve estar a ser passado correctamente, no entanto, a animacao só parece funcionar se usares no `$("html, body")`.

Assim

```
    var top = $(".sku").offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top }, 500);
```

Comment: Olá boa tarde, o problema é que esse exemplo retorna para o topo como retornasse valor 0

Comment: Tinha um typo, faltava o `.` no `$(".sku")`

Comment: Opa sim! tinha colocado, mas não é o problema, é como ele nao pegasse o valor da variavel

Comment: O que retorna se fizeres `$(".sku").length`?